# single and double cannot be augmented with a Measure

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

Does anyone know why the [< Measure>] type only augment some algebraic types? 
That so many useful types cannot be augmented with a Measure looks strange to me.

```
type FooType =
| FooByte       of byte<1>          // Error
| FooSbyte      of sbyte<1>         // Ok
| FooInt16      of int16<1>         // Ok
| FooUint16     of uint16<1>        // Error
| FooInt        of int<1>           // Ok
| FooInt32      of uint32<1>        // Error
| FooInt64      of int64<1>         // Ok
| FooUint64     of uint64<1>        // Error
| FooNativeint  of nativeint<1>     // Error
| FooUnativeint of unativeint<1>    // Error
| FooChar       of char<1>          // Error
| FooDecimal    of decimal<1>       // Ok
| FooFloat32    of float32<1>       // Ok
| FooSingle     of single<1>        // Error
| FooFLoat      of float<1>         // Ok
| FooDouble     of double<1>        // Error
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, there are two different issues here:

1. It appears that the unsigned types can't be annotated by design.  I'm not sure why this is, but you can get a pretty informative error message to this effect if you try something like `let _ = 1u<1>`.
2. Because of how type synonyms work, you can only use measures with "real" types and not with their synonyms.  This is why you can use measures with `float32` and `float`, but not `single` and `double`.  Note that the same would be true of `int32`, too.

Comment: And in case it's not clear to anyone, `float32` and `single` are the same thing, as are `float` and `double` - so the lack of single and double support is more about semantics than functionality.

Answer (score 4):

According to the spec, only the following literal types can have measures

```
  sbyte < measure-literal > //signed byte
  int16 < measure-literal >
  int32 < measure-literal >
  int64 < measure-literal >
  ieee32 < measure-literal > //float32
  ieee64 < measure-literal > //float
  decimal < measure-literal >
```

So this is why the unsigned types do not have measure types.  Also, form a physical perspective, almost any quantity with units can be negative, so this seems like a reasonable alternative.

The reason why the rest don't work is from the spec:

```
The F# core library defines the following types:

type float<[<Measure>] 'U>
type float32<[<Measure>] 'U>
type decimal<[<Measure>] 'U>
type int<[<Measure>] 'U>
type sbyte<[<Measure>] 'U>
type int16<[<Measure>] 'U>
type int64<[<Measure>] 'U>
```

which is why you can't do `single<1>` as there is no relevant type.